# helpme to solving npm create first project error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have an error like this:

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

`npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near 
'...egistry.npmjs.org/bab'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AFA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07- 
12T21_27_50_001Z-debug.log
```

Aborting installation.

```
  npm, install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom 
  react-scripts has failed.`

  Deleting generated file... package.json
  Deleting reactjs/ from C:\xampp\htdocs\firstprjs
  Done.
```

Cannot running the cache clean force, and the output will be the same as above.

Comment: Please put the console output / error message in code tags so that we can separate it from your question and text. If I get this right, it would also be helpful to paste the contents of your package.json in another code block.

Comment: How did you try to install React?

Comment: i just installing nodejs. and then i start to create project on command line based on react js guide. Maybe theres something missing on my steps? TT